# Cannot install Eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: dependencies, eclipse

I cannot install Eclipse from the Ubuntu Software Center. I get error: The following packages are not yet satisfied with dependencies:

```
eclipse-platform: Depends: eclipse-platform-data (> = 3.8.1-4) but 3.8.1-4 is installed 
                   Depends: eclipse-rcp (= 3.8.1-4) but 3.8.1-4 is installed 
                   Depends: liblucene2-java (<2.9.5) but 2.9.4 + ds1-4 will be installed 
                   Depends: sat4j (<2.4.0) but 2.3.2-1 is installed.
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use following commands after press `Ctrl+Alt+T`(for execute Terminal).

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform
```

I think that your `Trusty` distro have some issues related with software repositories and you can solve them via above commands.